# ExtJS 4. My tree panel doesn't render

Tags: extjs

*My tree panel doesn't render after removing and adding it*.

This is the `'selection change'` handler in my `grid panel`:

```
selectionChange : function(selmodel, selection, eOpts) {
    var selected = selection.length > 0;
    if (selected) {
        var view = Ext.getCmp('viewportCenterId');
        view.removeAll();
        if (selection[0].get('id') == '1') {
            view.add({
                xtype:'publicationTree'
            });
        } else if (selection[0].get('id') == '0') {
            view.add({
                xtype: 'userinfoform'
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`publicationTree` is my `tree panel`, *and it didn't render after it*.

When the area where I want to put this `tree panel` is loading the first time, *this code is working*. (I put the code in my tree panel by xtype).

```
{
    region: 'center',
    id: 'viewportCenterId',
    collapsible: false,
    width: '60%',
    border: true,
    items:{
        xtype:'publicationTree',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1.Try specify a layout instead of width and height:

```
{
    region: 'center',
    id: 'viewportCenterId',
    layout: 'fit',
    collapsible: false,
    width: '60%',
    border: true,
    items:{
        xtype:'publicationTree'
    }
}
```

2.Try call view.doLayout() manually after adding if issue still here.